# How can I handle fighting game collisions for complex animations?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, fighting-game

Imagine that I have an animation like this.

[image]

As you can see, this attack hits in three horizontal places.
The opponent facing this player could be hit mid and low (standing or crouching).

The same goes for this move:

[image]

If the opponent is crouching, standing or in air it gets hit because the fire circle hits all areas (low, mid and high)

How can I handle hit detection with this sort of animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way fighting games work is with attack and collision boxes *per frame*. This way there is not a high/mid/low hit per se, a high-kick could for example hit a jumping character.

In Street Fighter this looks like this:

[image: Zangief hits Blanka in Street Fighter]

The hit is scored if a red box hits a opponents blue box. Red being the attack box and blue hit boxes

In your example each frame of animation would define the red boxes, where a hit should be scored. In the 2nd animation- the flaming circle, you could remove hit boxes from that character rendering him invulnerable during that attack.

Sometimes there are additional block boxes, those nullify a hit. A character could for example be hit from the back but have a block up when hit from the front.

So: add hit and collision boxes to your anination information and check against those.

Comment: Well, i thought this would be a more complex thing but in terms of concept it's very simple. Thank you for your answer.